# Excel ran out of resources

Tags: excel

I have a formula `=AVERAGE(INDIRECT("D7:"&ADDRESS(16,COLUMN()-1)))` in a certain cell. In other cells of the same column, I have other variations of this formula for median, mode, and standard deviation. However, when I try to change values in my range, I get the error of "Excel ran out of resources while attempting to calculate one or more formulas". Is there a reason why this formula I have is giving Excel an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

INDIRECT and ADDRESS are volatile, use INDEX instead:

```
$D$7:INDEX(16:16,COLUMN()-1)
```

So

```
=AVERAGE($D$7:INDEX($16:$16,COLUMN()-1))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Is the $ in front of the 16 necessary? I'm assuming that is the number of rows in my range.  I'm still new to this and am just wondering what role it is playing in the formula.

Comment: No, but if you drag the formula down or up the 16s will change as it refers to the full row.

Comment: So I altered it to try and work for a different table on my spreadsheet, but I'm getting a reference error... =AVERAGE(($D$29:INDEX($30:$39,COLUMN()-1)))

Comment: `$30:$39` needs to be one row, use the last row you want: `$39:$39`

Comment: Okay that makes perfect sense. I appreciate all your help. Thank you for your patience!